# Bootstrap Table window.actionEvents calling ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

There is no result when i tried to obtain the result of a php executed by ajax call.

```js
window.actionEvents = {
    'click .abrir': function(e, value, row) {
      var titulo = row.tipo + " N° " + row.numero;
      var objeto = row.objeto;
      $modal.find('.modal-title').text(titulo);
      $modal.find('.modal-objeto').text(objeto);
      var docLocation = 'normasPDF/' + row.archivo;
      $('#pdf').attr('data', docLocation);
      $modal.modal('show');

    },
    'click .ver': function(e, value, row) {
      //Calling a javascript function there is no result
      var a = verAnalisis(row.id);
      alert("" + a);
    }
```

the function executes and by viewing the console there is a result that is on a html table.

```js
function verAnalisis(value) {
  var id = value;
  var res = "";
  /*echoes a  table html like <table><tr><td>5655</td></tr></table>*/
  $.post(
    "ExecVistaAnalisis.php", {
      id
    },
    function(data) {
      res = data;
    }
  );
  return res;
}
```

but when i tried to get this there is nothing, i don't know what is happening.
any idea.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I probed with:

```js
'click .ver': function(e, value, row) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        'id': row.id
      },
      url: "ExecVistaAnalisis.php",
      cache: false,
      success: function(response) {
        $('#divResults').append(response);
        $modalA.modal('show');
      }
    });
```

And it works, i really don't know why but i wisearch more.